# Ruby on Rails - how to instantiate an empty model and populate the object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create an empty model, populate it and then add it to the database.

I am looking through Google for the syntax for instantiating a simple model that I can set fields in, but there does not seem to be much documentation for that.

Is that just not the intended useage pattern? If it is, how can I just create the empty model?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your model already have a defined database structure?

Comment: We need more info. What do you mean by 'empty model'? One where there's no class defined for it at all, or something else... ?

Comment: What are you looking for beyond `Blah.create(:name => 'bob')`

Comment: @Casper no it doesn't, but I will need to define the db structure as I do it. It is mongo.

Comment: @x1a4 I meant something equivalent to Java's Obj x = new Obj();

Comment: @FrederickCheung that is close to what I am looking for, but what is the :name => 'bob' part?

Comment: This question needs extensive editing. What have you tried? How has it failed? And what are you *really* trying to accomplish here? *Why* is much more important than *how* in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ActiveRecord model works based on what fields it's related table has in your db. If you have no db yet you have no fields. The usage pattern goes like this:

```
$ rails g model client name:string
#stuff happens
$ rake db:migrate
```

You now have a model associated with a clients table that has a string attribute called name.

Now in your controller you can use this by

```
@client = Client.new
@client.name = "foo"
@client.save
```

Which will create the model object, set the name, and persist it to the db

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).  Your current issue is covered at this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-resource), but you really need to read up on getting started.